# Let $f$ be a non-constant holomorphic function in a domain $U$. Assume $z_0 ∈ U$ is a local minimum of $\lvert f\rvert$. Show that $f(z_0) = 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question from my homework:

> Let $f$ be a non-constant holomorphic function in a domain $U$. Assume $z_0 \in U$ is a local minimum of $|f|$. Show that $f(z_0) = 0$.

I know the maximum principle, but I can't figure out the minimum. I thought about Cauchy's integral for sub domain of $U$, but am unsure if that's any useful.

Comment: **Hint**. Remember the mean value property.

Comment: but i don't know if the function is harmonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $f(U)$ is open.
If $f(z_0)\neq 0$ **draw** the arrow from $0$ to $f(z_0)$ .
Don't compute anything, just **look** at the contradiction!

Comment: Dear @copper.hat: what I find nicest and most praiseworthy is the fair-play shown by a user having posted a solution and complimenting another answerer.

Comment: Thanks! Just wish I had thought of your approach :-).

Comment: how can i recall that f(U) is open?

Comment: The set of holomorphic functions on $U$ is often denoted $\mathcal O(U)$. If you are familiar with that notation you might use the mnemonic $\mathcal O \implies \operatorname {open}$ ...Or remember that the result is called "the open mapping theorem" .

Comment: Can you please tell me the contradiction? I am unable to get the contradiction. Is it giving the contradiction that $z_0$ is a local minimum?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f(x_0) \neq 0$, then with $g(x) = {1 \over f(x)}$, the function $x \mapsto |g(x)|$ has a local maximum at $x_0$. Applying the maximum modulus theorem to a small ball around $x_0$ shows that $g$ (and hence $f$) is constant.